# Есть ли глаголы, которые не могут употребляться в непереходном значении?

Tags: грамотная-речь, грамматика

Я не носитель русского языка, но мне кажется, что некоторые слова требуют явные дополнения, например *несём* :

```
- Что вы делаете?
- Мы несем ему книги.

- Что вы делаете?
- *Мы несем.
```

Мне кажется, что выражение "мы несем" без дополнений неправильно. Так ли в самом деле? Еще такие слова, как *дать* или *передать* могли бы служить примерами. Если я прав, то как составить список таких глаголов? Есть ли словари с соответствующими пометками?

Answer (score 3):

> Мне кажется, что выражение "мы несем" без дополнений неправильно

Это не так. Иногда прямое дополнение умалчивается по условиям контекста, иногда оно просто не нужно.

*' - А кто несет книги?

' - Мы несём.*

И в другом значении:

*От него несло перегаром.*

Вообще в русском нет глаголов, императивно требующих прямого дополнения. Словарей поэтому тоже нет. Хотя понятно, что некоторые глаголы без явного или подразумеваемого прямого дополнения недостаточны для точной передачи мысли. Иногда в таких случаях говорят о высокой и низкой степени переходности.

Не знаю, стоит ли вас сейчас посвящать в теоретические споры, но если для простоты, то есть глаголы непереходные (не допускающие при себе прямого дополнения) и переходные (требующие или допускающие при себе такое дополнение). В группе переходных иногда (не общепринято) выделяют подгруппу переходно-непереходных, которые в разных ситуациях могут или требовать дополнения, или не допускать его. Иногда даже считают, что это разные значения глагола.

Самый простой представитель такого типа - есть. В значении "насыщаться", "производить прием пищи" он непереходный, а в значении "поедать" - переходный.

Аналогично - глагол "дать". Он обычно переходный, но в значении "воздать" полностью теряет переходность.

И практически любой глагол так, включая и ваш "нести". И вот эти вещи вполне можно посмотреть в обычных толковых словарях.

Вот пример с глаголом "есть":
[есть | gramota.ru](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C&all=x)

Значения с высокой переходностью (начиная с третьего) отмечены примерами с прямым дополнением.